# SELECT option WHEN clicked

Tags: php

My code:

```
<div class="row visible-xs">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
                <?php

                    echo '<option selected disabled>Select a page</option>';

                    for($page = 1; $page <= $number_of_pages; $page++) {
                        echo '<option value="players.php?page='.$page.'#list">Page: '.$page.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Explanation:

This is how I decided to layout pagination on my page. So when a user clicks, for example, page 2, it redirects to players.php?page=2 and so on. The issue is that when an option from select menu clicked I want to make it selected. How can I make it?

The idea was to get a value from GET method and if it is equal to $page than it is selected..but I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it with PHP using the `$_GET` to retrieve the `page` query string. I have added a conditional statement to your `for` loop to check if the current page iteration is equal to the current page query string.

```
<div class="row visible-xs">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
                <?php
                    // Get current page from query string
                    $currentPage = $_GET['page'];

                    echo '<option selected disabled>Select a page</option>';
                    for($page = 1; $page <= $number_of_pages; $page++) {
                        // Check if current option in the loop is the current page
                        $selected = ($currentPage == $page) ? 'selected' : '';
                        // Add selected attribute to option if $selected = selected/
                        echo '<option ' . $selected . ' value="?page='.$page.'#list">Page: '.$page.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```